# pyspark check if value in the column adheres to a fixed format

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to check if column "*phone_number*" in my pyspark data frame is in a fixed format.

- format :
  *804-8048888*

**Request :**

- How can I check if all values in the column are in the above same
  format.
- As there is a "-" in the phone number i cant cast the column as `int`
  and check `is_valid()`

Comment: You can use regex to check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another way.

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([('1', '804-8048888'), ('2', '1234567890')]).toDF('id', 'phone')

from pyspark.sql.functions import *

df.withColumn('validate', expr("phone rlike '^[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{7}$'")).show()

+---+-----------+--------+
| id|      phone|validate|
+---+-----------+--------+
|  1|804-8048888|    true|
|  2| 1234567890|   false|
+---+-----------+--------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a test dataframe like this one :

```py
df.show()

+------------+
|phone_number|
+------------+
| 804-8048888|
|     8048888|
+------------+
```

with a regex, you can validate your format easily.

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df.withColumn(
    "is_valid",
    F.when(
        F.regexp_extract(F.col("phone_number"), r"\d{3}-\d{7}", 0)
        == F.col("phone_number"),
        True,
    ).otherwise(False),
).show()

+------------+--------+
|phone_number|is_valid|
+------------+--------+
| 804-8048888|    true|
|     8048888|   false|
+------------+--------+
```